# There is an Exception in following code. Oauth login with google-firebase in flutter

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-authentication, googlesigninaccount

When I try to log in with google the following exception is raised.

```
PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null).
```

How to solve this exception. I am stuck on this from 4 days.

```
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<FirebaseUser> _handleSignIn() async {
    GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();

    GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
    FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    print("signed in " + user.displayName + "  " + user.email);
    return user;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no error in your code then your Auth is complete.
but run code after this Process https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android

Answer (score -1):

It might come with the configurations, or may be `google_services.json` is not at right place.